# How to reverse words in a sentence using java

Tags: java, recursion

I'm trying to reverse the string e.g, **stack overflow** into ***overflow stack***, but my code is reversing whole String e.g, like **"hello"** into **"olleh"**.

I want to reverse the String but not finding the proper result. I want suggestions to improve my code to find the desired output.

The code I tried is:

```
public static String reverseString(String str)
    {
        if (str.isEmpty())
            return str;
        //Calling Function Recursively
        return reverseString(str.substring(1)) + str.charAt(0);
    }
```

Comment: You want to reverse words, not characters. How would you split a string into a list of words?

Comment: Yeah, that's what I m asking . Is there any way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1 - just use srting split method on given string.

2 - save output in an array.

3 - traverse array backward.

```
    String a = "stack overflow abc";
    String[] b = a.split("\\s+");
    for(int i = b.length-1 ; i>= 0 ; i--) {
        System.out.println(b[i]);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like this maybe:

```
public String getReversed(String text){
    List<String> wordList = Arrays.asList(text.split("\\s+"));
    Collections.reverse(wordList);
    return String.join(" ", wordList);
}
```